# How do I get the total number of messages being handled right now

Tags: nservicebus

We have an application that consists of many NSB workers that each handles one message, does one small thing, and queues up the next message (very microservice-ish).

For various reasons (mostly related to stable end-to-end automated tests) I would like to:

1. Stop processing any new messages
2. Wait until all currently processing messages are finished being processed
3. Clear the queue (among other things to stand up the test environment for the next test to be run)
4. Restart message processing.

1, 3, and 4 I have working right now via `ITransport.SetMaximumConcurrencyLevel`, but I am unsure of how to handle #2.  Is there any way to have NSB tell me how many threads are actively processing messages, so I can wait (or timeout) based on this?

Answer (score 0):

if it is for end-2-end testing and acceptance testing only I prefer to use the built-in Acceptance Test Framework. Take a look at this blog post for all the details:
https://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2014/10/25/automating-end-to-end-nservicebus-tests-with-nservicebus-acceptancetesting/

Comment: That's pretty cool.  I bookmarked it for later usage.  Unfortunately, we already have a home-grown test flow that we are using, and while I'd probably want to investigate moving to this right now that would be difficult to get the time.